# Prevent Assembly Reflector and its Access to other client/User

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, ant

I have created project  in  Windows Presentation Foundation which use some Assembly created by me and use in other project. But now i don't want others to use it and to reverse engineering ("Assembly to code").

i come to know about Assembly signing. Also i Have use ant try signing but i can easily Open code of Assembly in .Net reflector tool.

So please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Not possible. Signing doesn't at all do what you seem to think it does, either. If you give them your program, they can reverse it.

Comment: so what should i do to prevent dll access to others

Comment: Don't distribute it. Rethink why you want to prevent its use.

Comment: And by the way, "Don't distribute it" could actually be a viable option. For instance; you could run your code as a web service with a "dumb" client.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how much work you want to do, and how hard you want to make it.

If all you want is to stop people from being able to quickly decompile your assembly you can compress and/or encrypt the DLL itself, then write a loader for the assembly that brings it into memory, decodes and/or decompresses and loads the assembly in-memory.  The compressed/encrypted data can be stored as a resource in another assembly which handles the unpacking if you like, although that makes it simpler to find the code that does the unpack.

This will only prevent casual inspection of your code.  It won't slow down a determined reverse engineering attempt by much.  Ultimately there isn't much at all that you can do to stop a skilled and determined attempt at reverse engineering.

Comment: i dont know how to do it. if any example given then will try.

Comment: This is of course entirely correct. You pointed out a halfway decent option, and made clear it's significant limitation. @SagarPatel As for trying to implement such a thing, I think you are better off not doing so. I've done it before once when it was a requirement placed on me. It's a pain in the butt, and worse, *it doesn't solve the 'problem'*. The problem is: The machine has to be able to execute the code. If the machine can execute it, ultimately it can be reverse engineered.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I've done it once as an intellectual exercise.  Mostly I use the technique for bundling little third-party assemblies as resources rather trying to hide what I'm doing.  I just hate deploying 3 files when 1 will do :)

Comment: @Corey Oh yes; I definitely agree that can be a useful thing in some circumstances. I had to embed external assemblies like that in one really, really strange circumstance where I could only deploy a single file to the target system. Thank you for bringing up painful memories ;)